# Integrate node-sass-json-importer into an Angular CLI application

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular-cli, node-sass

Trying to add the [node-sass-json-importer](https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer) into an Angular CLI application.

I was using version `1.0.0-beta.17`of the CLI, but haven't been able to figure it out using the current version `1.2` either.  After installing it via yarn I don't know where it should be setup in the application configuration.

Has anyone successfully integrated this into their application?  The [only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35826460/1148107) I could find regarding this is for applications using Webpack, but not for the Angular CLI.

Answer (score 3):

> Solved this by changing the styles.js

```
node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/styles.js
```

In the above file , edit as mentioned below

```
const jsonImporter = require('node-sass-json-importer');
```

> and add  importer: jsonImporter in the rule for .scss

```
{ test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/, use: [{
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: cssSourceMap,
                        // bootstrap-sass requires a minimum precision of 8
                        precision: 8,
                        includePaths,
                        importer: jsonImporter,
                    }
                }]
        }
```

This might not be the best solution but solves your issue ,  there is no option  i can see to pass the args to node-sass here in this case it is --importer  './node_modules/node-sass-json-importer' ,

as per this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1791 it allows only includePaths option alone.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: Provided the above method , as you don't want to use webpack.
And by folllowing above method, your application will run with angular cli command ng serve without errors

Comment: Still holding out my breath that someone figures out a way which doesn't require hacking stuff directly in @angular/cli... but probably the best answer I am going to get :/

Comment: Yeah but looks like they haven't added it yet.....https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/styles.ts ....in the newer version

Comment: sorry, I'm not on that project anymore so I cannot provide any feedback about the usefulness

Comment: No problem this might help others :)!!

Comment: Anything new on this front in 2020 ?

Comment: looks like they haven't added yet as per this link

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/d29d40370a8ba1c849db1d3f28daf67961088b26/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/styles.ts#L135

Comment: it's still the same options, which allows includePaths alone

Comment: You can use [`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) to apply custom Webpack configuration, no need to modify any `node_modules` files which will get reverted after any install or update. Check my answer to @BuZz question [Angular: How to parse JSON variables into SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510735/angular-how-to-parse-json-variables-into-scss/60851939).

Answer (score -1):

If you use css-loader, You can enable module feature. Enabling that will gives you flexibility to import css just like requiring javascript object. I used for react, You can do the same for angular guess. It is very cool feature you should check this out.

```
//css 
.app p {
  color: green;
}

//JS
import styles from './app.css';

     <div className={styles.app}>
        <p>{ this.state.count }</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.increment()}>Increment</button>
      </div>
```

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader
https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/

Comment: -1 This question isn't about React or static css, and doesn't even solve the same issue with React (in React you would have to have your own webpack config where you would configure the sass add on)